# How can I set my top right hotcorner to open Terminal?

Tags: hot-corners, gnome-terminal

So, I'm completely new to Linux, and I have to learn the basic, but I can't make custom commands work in hot corners! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I went out of town so I'll do it when I return :)

Comment: Both answers helped me, but I had to install it as @Davin Miler said. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the custom command to `gnome-terminal`, your might have to install it first though. In case of the last use `sudo apt install gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 3):

You can set in Settings/Desktop under the *Hot Corners* tab (I put `pantheon-terminal` but you can choose `gnome-terminal` as well if you have installed it):

[image]